# Alternative to Logarithmic Spiral to simulate galaxies

Tags: functions, trigonometry, proof-explanation, logarithms

I was reading [this document](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0908/0908.0892.pdf) and in chapter 2. NEW FORMULA (page 2) , they suggested a better formula for realistic galaxies than the Logarithmic spiral:

And it says that the formula is given in radial form, where
$${r^-}^1$$
replaces x in the Gudermannian and scaling degrees of freedom are added:

$$r(θ)=\frac{A}{log(B\tan\frac{θ}{2N})}$$

I was trying to simulate the formula over at  [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) but couldn't put it together since I don't understand what they mean by $${r^-}^1$$

Formulas they mention:

Logarithmic Spiral:

$$r(θ)=r_0{e^k}^θ$$

Gudermannian:

$$r(θ)=2 \ {tan^-}^1(e^x)$$

This is what I expected:

[Picture with Examples of equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtxGr.png)

I wanted to change B and N to see the effects that would have on the result. I simply tried to put the formula on Desmos but an error occurs. Can you help me set it up?

Edit: What I get (My attempt of example A in page number 3):

[image: My attempt of example A in page number 3]

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> I didn't look at the paper and don't have ideas of what might be going on with Desmos, but I'd expect $r^{-1}$ refers to the reciprocal (and $\tan^{-1} = \arctan$ is the inverse tangent).